# DB2: Foreign key constraints between multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, db2, ddl

In DB2, suppose I have 3 tables: T1, T2, T3:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  T1_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
  T2_T1 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- parent entity ID from T1
  T2_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (T2_T1, T2_ID),
);

CREATE TABLE T3 (
  T3_T1 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- parent entity ID from T1
  T3_T2 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- parent entity ID from T2
  T3_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (T3_T1, T3_T2, T3_ID)
);
```

I would like to define FK relations in a way it would forbid deletion of record in T2 if there is a connected record in T3, but at the same time when I delete a record from T1 it should automatically delete records in T2 and T3 respectively.

Is it possible to define just FK constraints to satisfy these requirements? Or it can not be achieved without writing a code that would first delete appropriate records records from T3, then from T2 and only then from T1?

**Update**: an actual **DB2 10.5** code I'm trying to run:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  t1_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(t1_id)
)

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  t2_t1 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  t2_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (t2_t1, t2_id), 
  CONSTRAINT t2_fk_t1 
    FOREIGN KEY (t2_t1) 
    REFERENCES t1 (t1_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE t3 (
  t3_t1 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  t3_t2 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  t3_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (t3_t1, t3_t2, t3_id), 
  CONSTRAINT t3_fk_t1 
    FOREIGN KEY (t3_t1) 
    REFERENCES t1 (t1_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT t3_fk_t2 
    FOREIGN KEY (t3_t1, t3_t2) 
    REFERENCES t2 (t2_t1, t2_id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

The last `CREATE` statement fails with the following error:

> SQL20255N  FOREIGN KEY "T3_FK_T2" is not valid because it would cause
>   a descendent table "S.T3" to be delete-connected to its ancestor table
>   "S.T1" through multiple relationships with conflicting delete rules.
>   The conflict is between the delete rules of constraints
>   "S.T3.T3_FK_T1" and "S.T3.T3_FK_T2" on the descendent table.
>   Reason code = "3".  SQLSTATE=42915

Comment: Yes it may  be possible   *****WARNING*****    If you get a FK cascade wrong it will be disastrous cascade failure in your DB and rows will be deleted in both parent and child tables..  The safe way to do these is by specifying restrict.  with a foreign key restrict you have to manually delete records in each table much safer.   *****  Start by drawing a picture ******

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Even if it may seem a bit *strange*, it is not forbidden to have *overlapping* constraints.

---

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  t1_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  t2_t1 INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES t1(t1_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  , t2_id INTEGER NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY (t2_t1, t2_id)
);

CREATE TABLE t3 (
  t3_t1 INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES t1(t1_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  , t3_t2 INTEGER NOT NULL
        , FOREIGN KEY (t3_t1,t3_t2) REFERENCES t2(t2_t1,t2_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
  , t3_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (t3_t1, t3_t2, t3_id)
);
INSERT INTO t1 (t1_id) VALUES (11), (12),(13), (14), (15);
INSERT INTO t2 (t2_t1,t2_id) VALUES (11, 21), (12,22),(13,23), (14,24), (15,25);
INSERT INTO t3 (t3_t1,t3_t2,t3_id) VALUES (11, 21,31), (12,22,32),(13,23,33), (14,24,34), (15,25,35);


DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1_id = 13; -- should succeed
DELETE FROM t2 WHERE t2_id = 24; -- should fail

SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
SELECT * FROM t3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Simply create a foreign key from T3 to T2 and T1, T2 being a RESTRICT on delete and T1 having no action.

In T2, a foreign key to T1 also with a cascade delete.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  T1_ID INTEGER NOT NULL unique,
  PRIMARY KEY (T1_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
  T2_T1 INTEGER NOT NULL        constraint t2_t1_t1_id_fk
            references t1
                on delete cascade, -- parent entity ID from T1
  T2_ID INTEGER NOT NULL unique,
  PRIMARY KEY (T2_T1, T2_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE T3 (
  T3_T1 INTEGER NOT NULL constraint t3_t1_t1_id_fk
        references t1
            on delete cascade, -- parent entity ID from T1
  T3_T2 INTEGER NOT NULL constraint t3_t2_t2_id_fk
        references t2 (t2_id) on delete restrict, -- parent entity ID from T2
  T3_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (T3_T1, T3_T2, T3_ID)
);
```

Keep in mind you can also simply do it from the other perspective in case you want to have more strict foreign keys. (Foreign keys from the ID's towards the references!)

Worst case scenario there is always triggers, everything is possible. :)

Comment: I'm trying this in DB2 10.5 and it would not allow to define T3 with "conflicting delete rules"...

Comment: Oh dear. Never used DB2 sadly, I use Postgresql personally.

I've edited my answer with the full create script, just in case.

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated it the original post, will update now.